# Installing postgres on 13.04: no valid OpenPGP data found

Tags: apt, gnupg, postgresql

Following the [UbuntuGeek instructions for installing Postgres on Ubuntu 13.04](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-postgresql-9-2-on-ubuntu-13-04-server.html) (and [reinforced here](https://askubuntu.com/a/289388/135095)), I'm getting stuck at this command:

```
wget --quiet -O - http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

My system is responding:

```
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

In case it's relevant, my pgdg.list file contains only this line:

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main
```

What do I need to do to move forward?

Comment: Though if I proceed with `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.2` it seems to install Postgres 9.2 (after a warning about packages that "cannot be authenticated").

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce it. `wget --quiet -O - http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -` runs fine. You sure it wasn't the server that was down?

Comment: @Braiam truthfully, I'm not sure. But there is evidence it wasn't a one-time thing. This question still receives views (and votes), even 8 years later.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue following those instructions - try downloading the key separately  and then add it:

```
sudo wget http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ACCC4CF8.asc
```

then:

```
sudo apt-key add ACCC4CF8.asc
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Perfect. Worked for me as well.

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
wget --no-check-certificate --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add -
```

Reason: Seems there is a certificate error where wget does not accept the certificate issuer for for the website (try just the wget command before the pipe). Guess the correct way would be to install the correct root certificate and certificate chain, but letting wget just ignore it would be faster if you trust the site...