# Cannot add apt key to install Koha

Tags: software-installation, pgp

When I try to install Koha and run this command to add the key:

```
wget -o- http://debian.koha-community.org/koha/gpg.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

I always get this error message:

```
 gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found
```

Even after re-installing Ubuntu.

[image: terminal window]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing postgres on 13.04: no valid OpenPGP data found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/352539/installing-postgres-on-13-04-no-valid-openpgp-data-found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try downloading the key separately and then add it:

```
sudo wget http://debian.koha-community.org/koha/gpg.asc
```

After that, execute:

```
sudo apt-key add gpg.asc
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Nice! Good for you. :)