# how to remove postgres 9.3 and install 9.2

Tags: software-installation, 13.04, postgresql, downgrade

I want to install postgres 9.2 and remove 9.3 on ubuntu 13.04 ,  since I want to install a software and they recommand postgress 9.2, thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/287786/how-to-install-postgresql-on-ubuntu-13-04

Answer (score 0):

If you installed `postgresql` from graphical installer, run uninstall.run file from `dir` where 9.3 was installed `/opt/lib/postgresql/9.3 or /var/lib/postgresql/9.3`. It will uninstall 9.3 from your computer.